# Use IEnumerable method in other class C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Well I have a class Person:

```
 public class Person
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons(string path)
    {
        var personlist = new List<Person>();
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var split = line.Split(";");
            var firstName = split[0];
            var lastName = split[1];
            var age = split[2];

            Person person = new Person
            {
                firstName = firstName,
                lastName = lastName,
                age = int.Parse(age),
            };
            personlist.Add(person);
        }

        return personlist;
    }
}
```

And in my Main method I'd like to asign the method `GetPersons(string path)` to a list

```
var list = new List<Person>();
list = GetPersons("persons.csv");
```

I does not compile with error CS0103: The name 'GetPersons' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Putting loader methods in the entity itself isn't a good idea. What happens if you want to load from a different source, like a JSON file or database? You may want to load the same class from different sources too, eg from a JSON file during testing and a database during production

Comment: Unrelated: there is no point in creating a new list, if the variable holding its reference is reset to another list right in the next line.

Answer (score 1):

You've made `GetPersons` an *instance* method which means you'd need an instance of a `Person` to call it - this doesnt quite make sense for what you're doing.

There is some sense in making it `static`:

```
public class Person
{    
    public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons(string path)
    {
        // ... //
    }
}
```

Then call it as:

```
var list = Person.GetPersons("persons.csv");
```

But you should consider if the `Person` class is the *correct* place for this code.

Comment: @xinip10 ha, no worries. We all make simple mistakes.

Comment: @xinip10 you shouldn't be putting loading code in entity classes at all. What happens if you want to load from a different source, like a JSON file or database?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was thinking the same thing as you added that so hence the edited last line.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a new instance of **Person** class and then call **GetPersons**. Try like:

```
var list = new List<Person>();
var person = new Person();
list = person.GetPersons("persons.csv");
```

Comment: That may solve the immediate problem *but* it's really ugly. A better solution would be to convert the method to a static. Even better - don't put the loading code in `Person` at all. Sooner or later the OP will need to load the data from a different source

Comment: That answer's like suggesting to _run not walk_ from fountain to bathtub because the bucket has a hole instead of fixing the hole. :(